# Error with PrivateMessages in IdIRC

Tags: delphi, indy

Hi I have a problem with the following code:

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, idIRC, idContext, idGlobal;


// procedure TForm1.IdIRC1PrivateMessage(ASender: TIdContext; const ANickname,
// AHost, ATarget, AMessage: string);

// procedure TForm1.IdIRC1Raw(ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean;
// const AMessage: string);

procedure IrcPrivateMessage(ASelf: Pointer; const ANickname, AHost, ATarget,
  AMessage: string);
begin
  Writeln('[+] Message ' + ANickname + ' > ' + AMessage);
end;

procedure IrcRaw(ASelf: Pointer; ASender: TIdContext; AIn: Boolean;
  const AMessage: String);
begin
  Writeln(iif(AIn, '[Recv] ', '[Sent] ') + AMessage);
end;

var
  irc: TIdIRC;
  m1: TMethod;
  m2: TMethod;

begin
  try
    irc := TIdIRC.Create(nil);
    try
      irc.Host := 'localhost';
      irc.Port := 6667;
      irc.Nickname := 'tester';
      irc.Username := 'tester';

      m1.Code := @IrcRaw;
      m1.Data := irc;
      irc.OnRaw := TIdIRCRawEvent(m1);

      m2.Code := @IrcPrivateMessage;
      m2.Data := irc;
      irc.OnPrivateMessage := TIdIRCPrivMessageEvent(m2);

      try
        irc.Connect;
      except
        Writeln('Nay');
        Exit;
      end;

      Writeln('Yeah');

      irc.Join('#locos');

      while ('1' = '1') do
      begin
        //
      end;

    finally
      irc.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

The problem is when I receive a private message, the ANickname entry gives me the following error:

Project test.exe raised exeption class #C00000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00404673:read of adress 0x03cf4e58

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`TIdIRCPrivMessageEvent` is a "procedures of object", which implicitly references the object. You added a `Self` parameter for that, but you omitted the `TIdContext` parameter that is also part of the event:

```
procedure IrcPrivateMessage(ASelf: Pointer; Sender: TIdContext; const ANickname, AHost, ATarget, AMessage: string);
begin
   ....
end;
```

Comment: your code gives me error: [DCC Error] test.dpr(20): E2029 ';', ')' or '=' expected but ':' found

Comment: Change the offending `:` to `;`.